# How to use --ask-become-pass with ansible 1.9.4

Tags: ansible

I am a new user to ansible. I am attempting to use the privilege escalation feature to append a line to a file owned by root.

The following documentation tells me I can use --ask-become-pass with become_user to be prompted for the become_user password but I have no idea how to use it.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html

My current code I am working with is as follows:

```
- name: Add deploy to sudoers
        remote_user: me
        become: yes
        become_method: su
        ask_become_pass: true
        lineinfile:
          dest=/etc/somefile
          line=sometext
          regexp="^sometext"
          owner=root
          state=present
          insertafter=EOF
          create=True
```

Which gives me the error:
ERROR: ask_become_pass is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Can anyone give me an idea of what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

The doc says that `ask_become_pass` is a command line parameter. Which means you have to use it while executing the playbook:

`ansible-playbook *playbook-name* --ask-become-pass`
In this case ansible will ask for the password.

The other option `ansible_become_pass` can be used in the inventory or also as an extra_var. There you can set the password while executing the playbook.

Comment: Thanks @Capri90 for the answer. Your example worked exactly as you explained. Unfortunately, I am still getting a permission denied error. It seems the become_user re-establishes an ssh connection as the user I want to become. Since I want to su to root on the remote system (Ubuntu), that is not possible.  

How could I su to root without re-establishing an ssh connection? Is that even possible?  The end result is I want is to give a user admin rights without a password prompt. The equivalent of username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL  

I haven’t been able to figure out way to do this successfully.

Comment: You're welcome. Ubuntu does allow root access via ssh. Just change the settings. Otherwhise I am not sure if you want to create a user (use ansible module for that) or change an existing user.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great answers by @Capri90 and @vijay you can also specify a configuration to ask for the 'become pass' by default. This is documented under [DEFAULT_BECOME_ASK_PASS in the Ansible Configuration Settings documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-become-ask-pass). You can specify it using an environment variable or set it in an Ansible configuration file.

I use it in a `ansible.cfg` file in the repository:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_ask_pass = true
```

`ansible.cfg` is one of the default locations for the Ansible Configuration file. (more about default locations in [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file))

Answer (score 1):

**@Capri90** showed how to use

**BUT**

When `--ask-become-pass` is used user will need to **MANUALLY** enter password every time , so to avoid it follow bellow steps

Instead use below configuration

> **playbook.yml**

```
---
- hosts: yo_my_ips
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks: 
  - name: Install latest version of "npm" 
    apt:
      name: npm
      state: latest
```

> **ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
inventory = yo_ansible_inventory.txt
```

> **yo_ansible_inventory.txt**

**Note** : `ansible_become_pass` will be used when command `sudo apt-get install npm` is fired

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=tom    
ansible_become_pass=jerrypassword

[yo_my_ips]
192.168.1.105
```